# Правило редиректа на главную страницу

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, оптимизация-сайтов

Какое правило нужно написать в файле `.htaccess` чтобы сработал редирект с  `http://site.ru/index.php/ru` - на `http://site.ru/ru/`?

Answer (score 0):

Это правило `Redirect 301 from to`, должно работать,

```
Redirect 301 http://site.ru/index.php/ru http://site.ru/ru/
```

Comment: Правило не сработало(

Comment: @Сергей проверь стоит ли в начале .htaccess:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On`

Comment: RewriteEngine включен